# Whats is the LDAP Authentication best practice?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, phpldapadmin

I want to know the best practice for authenticating users using `OpenLDAP`. I could perform a search using the `cn`.

But then what if I got multiple hits with similar `cn` (under different ancestors of course) and they all use the same password?

I tried to use `uids` but then I got some types of accounts that do not use uids (like mail accounts and the admin `cn`). Also, when I added some users under the admin `cn` (which has no `uid`) I could not login with the admin `cn`.

What is the unique key that identifies a user?

**Note**: I am using `phpldapadmin` to manage the active directory, and `openldap` for the c++ code.

Comment: What you're really asking is how to individuate users. Email addresses tend to be unique, as do 'screen-names', unless you're running StackOverflow.

Comment: yea but even under the admin cn there is no email address and you can't add one at least not from phpldapadmin. I am looking for a generic way to uniquely identify users (if it exists in ldap, I don't know!).

Comment: LDAP does not enforce the use off a unique and common identifier attribute for all entries. But usually, Administrators are. You can search for either uid or cn. But if the search returns more than 1 entry, you have ambiguiity and cannot proceed with authentication. Alternately you can make sure you're admin have a unique uid (it doesn't have to be part of the DN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your OpenLDAP server to perform the [uniqueness check](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Attribute%20Uniqueness) on your chosen attribute. `CN` is not the most favorable attribute to choose for uniqueness I would choose `UID` attribute and have a policy in place for username generation.

Comment: I went for that, apparently it's the best choice available.